# How to create a multi page form with ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Currently working on my first ionic app using angular. I want the form for users profiles to have multiple pages as there is a lot of data to be taken in.

At the moment I have all my pages set to take in the value entered into the form and return that value in the console. I'm now trying to get that data to be stored locally and be returned after the form is complete.

The trouble I am having is with taking the data in after each page. The Error I am receiving is: Expected 11 arguments, but got 2. the rest of the 'arguments' are on other pages of the form.

Is there a way of avoiding this issue? I know I could have my form on one page, but from a UX point of view, separate pages would work better.

Any help would be appreciated.

CODE:

artist.modul.ts:

```
    export class Artist {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public rating: number,
    public genre: string,
    public imageUrl: string,
    public cost: number,
    public equipment: string,
    public descrpition: string,
    public band: string,
    public location: string,
    public type: string,
    public userId: string
    ) {}

}
```

music-type.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ArtistService } from '../../artist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-music-type',
  templateUrl: './music-type.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./music-type.page.scss'],
})
export class MusicTypePage implements OnInit {
  aForm: FormGroup;
  venType = [
    { name: 'Pub', isChecked: false },
    { name: 'Club', isChecked: false },
    { name: 'Wedding', isChecked: false },
    { name: 'Event', isChecked: false }
  ];

  constructor(private artistService: ArtistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.aForm = new FormGroup({
      band: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      type: new FormControl(null, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        validators: [Validators.required]
      })
    });
  }

  onCreateArtist(){
    if (!this.aForm.valid){
      return;
    }
    console.log(this.aForm);
    this.artistService.addArtist(this.aForm.value.band, this.aForm.value.type);
  }
}
```

music-type.page.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <form [formGroup]="aForm">
    <ion-grid class="ion-padding">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
          <h1 class="ideal">YOUR IDEAL VENUE</h1>
          <h2>What is the name of your band?</h2>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-item lines="none" type="text" class="box">
            <ion-input formControlName="band"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2">
          <h2>What type of venue are you looking for?</h2>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let venType of venType">
              <ion-label>{{ venType.name }}</ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox formControlName="type" slot="start" [(ngModel)]="venType.isChecked" ></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </form>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer lines="none">
  <ion-grid class="ion-padding">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="12" size-sm="8" offset-sm="2" class="ion-text-center">
        <ion-button
        (click)="onCreateArtist()"
        [disabled]="!aForm.valid"
        routerLink="/tabs/tab1/discover/new-artist/music-location"
          >Next</ion-button
        >
        <ion-button
          expand="block"
          fill="clear"
          routerLink="/tabs/tab1/discover/new-artist"
          routerDirection="backward"
          >Back</ion-button
        >
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: You have to make separate forms for all pages. and send data via routerParams to next page.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Would that mean making several 'artist.modul.ts? or can I link them together with routerParams

Comment: no you don't need to make multiple module files. check this: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-pass-data-from-one-component-to-another-in-angular-a9725733da12

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few options to build a multi-step form :

- Keep all the forms on a single page, but only show the active step. You can have a `step: number` variable and choose the right step to display using a ngSwitch.
- You can pass data through the navigation extra `state` parameter, then other pages will retrieve this data from their constructor (cf NavigationExtras#state doc), and the final page will submit it all.
- You can pass the form data as a query parameter (transformed into base64 JSON for example)
- You can store the data in a service.

Comment: When you say store the data in a service do you mean to have the onCreateArtist function in service and call it in each form page?

Comment: You choose : it can be a single FormGroup shared by all step components, or call onCreateArtistStep and accumulate the data and send it at the final step, or any other way that suits you. With a service, you will be able to share a variable with all your app screens.